# How to fix 'HTTP Response Code was 403 Forbidden' error in bitmovin-javascript on node.js server

Tags: javascript, bitmovin-player

I'm using bitmovin-javascript on a node.js server. I'm trying to create encodings for videos on my firebase storage and save the output in my bitmovin account using the bitmovin-javascript api.

I've upgraded from the old bitmovin api (v1) for javascript (which is now deprecated) and I'm implementing the current one (v2). But every time I run the code, it shows **HTTP Request was unsuccessful: HTTP Response Code was 403 Forbidden** in my terminal console.

I have cross-checked and ensured that the API keys I'm using to read  from the firebase storage (accesss-key & secret-key) are the valid ones as well as the bitmovin API key is also a valid one. The output-id is for bitmovin is also a valid one.

The api generates inputs and *video-codec-configuarations*, *audio-codec-configurations* & *manifests* but does not generate *outputs* or *encodings*.

The error seems to be occurring at the point where the api is trying to create an encoding resource.

Here's how my code looks like:

```
const Bitmovin = require('bitmovin-javascript').default;


const start = async () => {
  const bitmovin = Bitmovin({ 'apiKey': 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx' });

  // create the input
  const input = await bitmovin.encoding.inputs.gcs.create({
    name: 'Input',
    accessKey: 'GOOGXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
    secretKey: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
    bucketName: 'project-name.appspot.com'
  });

  // create the output
  const outputId = "XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX";

  // create the video and audio codec configurations
  const videoCodecConfig1 = await bitmovin.encoding.codecConfigurations.h264.create({
    name: 'H264 Codec Config',
    bitrate: 240000,
    width: 384,
    profile: 'HIGH'
  });

  const audioCodecConfig = await bitmovin.encoding.codecConfigurations.aac.create({
      name: 'my-aac-128kbit-cc',
      bitrate: 128000, // 128 KBit/s
      rate: 48000
  });

  // create the encoding resource
  const encoding = await bitmovin.encoding.encodings.create({
     name: 'Encoding',
     cloudRegion: 'AUTO',
     encoderVersion: '2.12.1'
  });

  // add the video and audio streams to the encoding
  const inputPath = 'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/project-name.appspot.com/o/new%2Fvideos%2Fsample.mp4?alt=media&token=XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX';

  const videoStreamConfig1 = {
    codecConfigId: videoCodecConfig1.id,
    inputStreams: [{
      inputId: input.id,
      inputPath: inputPath,
      selectionMode: 'AUTO'
    }]
  };

  const streamVideo1 = await bitmovin.encoding.encodings(encoding.id).streams.add(videoStreamConfig1);

  const audioStreamConfig = {
      codecConfigId: audioCodecConfig.id,
      inputStreams: [{
          inputId: input.id,
          inputPath: inputPath,
          selectionMode: 'AUTO'
      }]
  };
  const audioStream = await bitmovin.encoding.encodings(encoding.id).streams.add(audioStreamConfig);

  // add the video muxings to the encoding
  const segmentLength = 4;
  const outputPath = 'XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX/' + Date.now();
  const segmentNaming = 'seg_%number%.m4s';
  const initSegmentName = 'init.mp4';

  const fmp4VideoMuxingConfig1 = {
    segmentLength,
    segmentNaming,
    initSegmentName,
    streams: [{
      streamId: streamVideo1.id
    }],
    outputs: [{
      outputId: outputId,
      outputPath: outputPath + '/video/384_240000/fmp4/',
      acl: [{
        permission: 'PUBLIC_READ'
      }]
    }]
  };

  const videoMuxing1 = await bitmovin.encoding.encodings(encoding.id).muxings.fmp4.add(fmp4VideoMuxingConfig1);

  // add the audio muxing to the encoding
  const fmp4AudioMuxingConfig = {
    segmentLength,
    segmentNaming,
    initSegmentName,
    streams: [{
      streamId: audioStream.id
    }],
    outputs: [{
      outputId: outputId,
      outputPath: outputPath + '/audio/128000/fmp4/',
      acl: [{
        permission: 'PUBLIC_READ'
      }]
    }]
  };

  const fmp4AudioMuxing = await bitmovin.encoding.encodings(encoding.id).muxings.fmp4.add(fmp4AudioMuxingConfig);

  //create the manifest
  const manifestConfig = {
    name: 'Manifest',
    manifestName: 'manifest.mpd',
    outputs: [{
      outputId: outputId,
      outputPath: outputPath,
      acl: [{
        permission: 'PUBLIC_READ'
      }]
    }]
  };

  const manifest = await bitmovin.encoding.manifests.dash.create(manifestConfig);
  const period = await bitmovin.encoding.manifests.dash(manifest.id).periods.add({});

  let videoAdaptationSet = {

  };

  let audioAdaptationSet = {
    lang: 'en'
  };

  videoAdaptationSet = await bitmovin.encoding.manifests
    .dash(manifest.id)
    .periods(period.id)
    .adaptationSets.video.create(videoAdaptationSet);


  audioAdaptationSet = await bitmovin.encoding.manifests
    .dash(manifest.id)
    .periods(period.id)
    .adaptationSets.audio.create(audioAdaptationSet);


  // Adding Audio Representation

  const fmp4AudioRepresentation = {
    type: 'TEMPLATE',
    encodingId: encoding.id,
    muxingId: fmp4AudioMuxing.id,
    segmentPath: 'audio/128000/fmp4'
  };

  await bitmovin.encoding.manifests
    .dash(manifest.id)
    .periods(period.id)
    .adaptationSets(audioAdaptationSet.id)
    .representations.fmp4
    .add(fmp4AudioRepresentation);

  // Adding Video Representation

  const fmp4VideoRepresentation1 = {
    type: 'TEMPLATE',
    encodingId: encoding.id,
    muxingId: videoMuxing1.id,
    segmentPath: 'video/384_240000/fmp4'
  };

  await bitmovin.encoding.manifests
    .dash(manifest.id)
    .periods(period.id)
    .adaptationSets(videoAdaptationSet.id)
    .representations.fmp4
    .add(fmp4VideoRepresentation1);

  // start the encoding
  await bitmovin.encoding.encodings(encoding.id).start();


  // wait for the encoding to be finished
  await finish(encoding);

  //start and wait for the manifest to be finished
  await bitmovin.encoding.manifests.dash(manifest.id).start();

  console.log('Generating DASH manifest...');

  const waitForManifestToBeFinished = async () => {
    let manifestResponse;

    do {
      await bitmovin.encoding.manifests
          .dash(manifest.id)
          .status()
          .then(response => {
            console.log('DASH Manifest status is ' + response.status);
            manifestResponse = response;
          });

      await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 2000));
    }
    while (manifestResponse.status === 'RUNNING' || manifestResponse.status === 'CREATED');
  };

  await waitForManifestToBeFinished();

  console.log('Everything finished...');

  function getStatus(encoding) {
    return bitmovin.encoding.encodings(encoding.id).status();
  }

  function finish(encoding, interval = 5 * 1000, timeout = 5 * 60 * 1000) {
    let t, s = new Date();

    const check = (resolve, reject) => {
      clearTimeout(t);

      t = setTimeout(() => {
        getStatus(encoding)
          .then(current => {
            console.log('Encoding progress: ' + current.progress);

            if (current.status === 'FINISHED') {
              return resolve(current);
            }

            if (current.status === 'ERROR') {
              return reject('Encoding error');
            }

            if (new Date() - s >= timeout) {
              return reject('Timeout reached');
            }

            check(resolve, reject);
          });
      }, interval);
    }

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      check(resolve, reject);
    });
  }
  }
  start().catch(e => console.log(e.message));
```

I expect the api to read my firebase storage, encode the video from that storage, store it under my bitmovin outputs, provide me with a bitmovin link to the output so that I can save it to my own database.

Help on this would greatly be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't noticed any specific issue with the code snippet you provided so far. The issue could however be caused by another factor, such as the input / output settings or the input file itself.

Please feel free to reach out to [support@bitmovin.com](http://support@bitmovin.com) and provide the encoding ID as well as the input file in order for us to investigate this into more detail.